# Python: Why would a **kwarg of a subclass method be passed as a parameter in __call__() signature of the base class? Results in TypeError

Tags: python, inheritance, keras, conv-neural-network, loss-function

Sorry for the vague title, can't have a lot of characters.

**Brief exposition**:
I am implementing an Auto Encoder CNN architecture for an image analysis program that requires custom loss functions that don't exist in the keras back end or anywhere in tensorflow. That is no big deal; I like numerical computing and will gladly brush up my OOP skills.
In order for my program to run smoothly, I need my loss functions to be callable objects (basically how keras implements their loss objects, so I mirrored my loss classes based on the Keras Loss source code). It has been great and I've learned tons so far. I have a class `ReconstructionLoss(LossWrapper):` that is a subclass of `LossWrapper(Loss):` which is a subclass of parent `Loss(object):`. Specifically, instances of ReconstructionLoss need a tensor, 'DecodeOut' kwarg, but there are other classes of different loss types don't need this kwarg tensor. They all need y_true and EncodeOut args.

**Problem**:
ReconstructionLoss instances should be able to take a **kwargs (always 'DecodeOut' = someTensor). BUT somehow the kwarg is getting passed to the `__call__()` signature  in the parent class `Loss()`, resulting in a `TypeError: __call__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'DecodeOut'`. I think this happens when the LossWrapper `call()` method is utilized in the body of `__call__(self, arg1, arg2):` in the Loss class. It will just become more convoluted (haha) if I keep talking about it, so I will let you look at the code to see the rest of the details yourself. I'm sure I'm making a very subtle rookie mistake, as it has been a minute since I've had to do any OOP. Apologies for any weird indentations; it was a hassle copying and pasting it over in the code block on here. (I'm only showing relevant modules here as well):

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

import sys,os 
from pathlib import Path
from matplotlib import pyplot, cm
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_io as tfio
import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.python.framework import tensor_util
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as KB
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import tf_utils
from tensorflow.python.ops.losses import util as tf_losses_util
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import losses_utils

class Loss(object):

    def __init__(self): 
        print('Loss Object Instantiated')
    #HERE IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR once compilation gets here. 
    #kwarg 'DecodeOut' is being passed as a parameter
    # in __call__(self, y_true, EncodeOut, sample_weight = None).
    #It should only be called in the *return value* of the call() method
    # defined in LossWrapper class.
    def __call__(self, y_true, EncodeOut, sample_weight = None):#boom, error
    
        graph_ctx = tf_utils.graph_context_for_symbolic_tensors(
            y_true,EncodeOut, sample_weight)
        with KB.name_scope(self.__class__.__name__), graph_ctx:

            losses = self.call(y_true,EncodeOut) 
            return losses_utils.compute_weighted_loss(losses, sample_weight)


    def call(self, y_true, EncodeOut):
    """Invokes the `Loss` instance.

    Args:
      y_true: Ground truth values, with the same shape as 'y_pred'.
      y_pred: The predicted values.
    """
    NotImplementedError('Must be implemented in subclasses.')
    
 class LossWrapper(Loss):
        def __init__(self, func, **kwargs):
            super(LossWrapper, self).__init__()
            self.func = func
            self.func_kwargs = kwargs

     #See below, def call(self, y_true, EncodeOut), RETURNS
     #reconstruction_loss(y_true,EncodeOut, **self.func_kwargs),
     #but the kwarg = 'DecodeOut' is getting passed in the __call()__ signature when I implement:
     # recon_loss_obj = ReconstructionLoss()
     # reconLoss = recon_loss_obj (trueLabels, someTensor, DecodeOut = someOtherTensor)

     def call(self, y_true, EncodeOut):
             return self.func(y_true,EncodeOut, **self.func_kwargs)
    

class ReconstructionLoss(LossWrapper):
     def __init__(self, DecodeOut = [0]):
    
        super(ReconstructionLoss, self).__init__(
            reconstruction_loss, #this is the value of 'func' in all instances, 
                                 #function defined at below
            DecodeOut = DecodeOut)
        self.DecodeOut = DecodeOut

 def reconstruction_loss( y_true, residual, DecodeOut = [0]):
      print(DecodeOut.shape)
      K  = tf.size(residual[0,:,:,:]).numpy()
      L1_norm_batches = tf.norm(residual-DecodeOut, ord = 1, axis = [-3,-2])
      reconstruction_loss = np.sum(L1_norm_batches.numpy())/K
      return reconstruction_loss
```

Implementaion Example:

```
      loss_object = ReconstructionLoss()
      a=loss_object(y_true_train, conv11, DecodeOut = select) 

      Loss Object Instantiated
      Traceback (most recent call last):

         File "C:\Python File\Tamper.py", line 794, in <module>
         a=loss_object(y_true_train, conv11, DecodeOut = select)

         TypeError: __call__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'DecodeOut'
```

I am failing to see why 'DecodeOut' is being passed to the `__call__()`  signature to begin with, when it should only be passed to `self.func(y_true, EncodeOut, **kwarg)`  (in which case `self.func = reconstruction_loss` WHENEVER the `ReconstructionLoss()` object is instantiated.

I know it is a lot of info for what will probably be a very obvious mistake, but I'm trying to be as exhaustive as possible. If you are wondering why I am taking this approach, it is because I have several other loss objects (reconstructionloss vs. activation loss for instance) that I need to be able to call AND I'm doing this to learn. Furthermore, I am confused because this implementation is a directly analogous to the Keras Loss source code... they take the EXACT same approach as far as I am concerned.
Please look at their code if you'd like, specifcally just Loss, LossFunctionWrapper and then the class for BinaryCrossEntropy and the function binary_cross_entropy:

```
    https://keras-gym.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.html
```

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something subtle that those devs did that I don't know about OR I have sever misunderstanding of what is happening with the inheritance.
I have already tried defining all self attributes before super() is called with no success... not even sure if that is appropriate here.
**For those wondering why this is designed this way, here is an example snippet  of keras code with Loss, Wrapper, LossTypeClass, function of loss type with kwargs:** The Keras code is a bit more crowded, as they have several more optional arguements like reduction, name, etc.

```
class Loss(object):


    def __init__(self, reduction=losses_utils.ReductionV2.AUTO,name=None):
         losses_utils.ReductionV2.validate(reduction)
         self.reduction = reduction
         self.name = name

    def __call__(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):

        # If we are wrapping a lambda function strip '<>' from the name as it is not
        # accepted in scope name.
        scope_name = 'lambda' if self.name == '<lambda>' else self.name
        graph_ctx = tf_utils.graph_context_for_symbolic_tensors(
        y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)
        with K.name_scope(scope_name or self.__class__.__name__), graph_ctx:
            losses = self.call(y_true, y_pred)
        return losses_utils.compute_weighted_loss(
        losses, sample_weight, reduction=self._get_reduction())

class LossFunctionWrapper(Loss):

   def __init__(self,
                fn,
                reduction=losses_utils.ReductionV2.AUTO,
                name=None,
                **kwargs):
     super(LossFunctionWrapper, self).__init__(reduction=reduction, name=name)
     self.fn = fn
     self._fn_kwargs = kwargs

   def call(self, y_true, y_pred):

     if tensor_util.is_tensor(y_pred) and tensor_util.is_tensor(y_true):
       y_pred, y_true = tf_losses_util.squeeze_or_expand_dimensions(
           y_pred, y_true)
     return self.fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)

class BinaryCrossentropy(LossFunctionWrapper):

   def __init__(self,
           from_logits=False,# a kwarg not passed in __call__() of Loss(), passed when you call the instantiation of BinaryCrossentropy().
           label_smoothing=0,# same
           reduction=losses_utils.ReductionV2.AUTO,
           name='binary_crossentropy'):
     super(BinaryCrossentropy, self).__init__(
         binary_crossentropy,
         name=name,
         reduction=reduction,
         from_logits=from_logits,
         label_smoothing=label_smoothing)
     self.from_logits = from_logits


def binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=False,  label_smoothing=0):  # pylint: disable=missing-docstring
   y_pred = ops.convert_to_tensor(y_pred)
   y_true = math_ops.cast(y_true, y_pred.dtype)
   label_smoothing = ops.convert_to_tensor(label_smoothing,dtype=K.floatx())

   def _smooth_labels():
     return y_true * (1.0 - label_smoothing) + 0.5 * label_smoothing

   y_true = smart_cond.smart_cond(label_smoothing,
                             _smooth_labels, lambda: y_true)
  return K.mean(
      K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits), axis=-1)
```

~Thanks

Comment: "I am failing to see why 'DecodeOut' is being passed to the `__call__()` signature to begin with, when it should only be passed to `self.func(y_true, EncodeOut, **kwarg)`" - ...why did you expect that? If you pass arguments in `some_object(...)`, those arguments are going straight to the `__call__` method.

Comment: Why are you passing `DecodeOut` there, anyway? It looks like it's supposed to be a constructor parameter.

Comment: I was trying to learn some relevant OOP from the Keras Loss source code and this is exactly how they implement. It makes sense to me as I understand it now, but I could be wrong with my understanding (hence the error and confusion). I provided the link with some keywords to quickly find the relevant code with cntrl+f. I figured it was exemplary code, but that could have been my first mistake. It will take a few minutes for me to give reasonable answers to your questions based on my current understanding.

Comment: "and this is exactly how they implement" - I don't see anything in your link that resembles the buggy `loss_object(y_true_train, conv11, DecodeOut = select)` call.

Comment: Look at Loss(object)'s method __call__(), specifcally self.call(). Then look at the definition of the call() function in the LossWrapper class. Then look at class BinaryCrossEntropy() and its **kwargs and fn attributes. Then look at the function def binary_cross_entropy()'s use of kwargs. You implement that like loss_obj = BinaryCrossEntropy() and then call loss_obj(whateverArgs, from_logits = True/False, label_smoothing = constant), where from_logits and label_smoothing are **kwargs that don't get called in __call__() of Loss(object). Am I missing something ?

Comment: "You implement that like loss_obj = BinaryCrossEntropy() and then call loss_obj(whateverArgs, from_logits = True/False, label_smoothing = constant)" - no you don't. Why do you think that?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica and THAT would be the incredibly obvious mistake I was talking about... sheesh that is a bit embarrassing. I had it stuck in my head that the kwarg was passed when you call the instance of BinaryCrossEntropy() instead of it being defined when you instantiate it... Thank you for your time, patience, and speed!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with code, lazy understaing of OOP, implemented the code incorrectly. `kwargs` should be passed when you instantiate the object, not when you are trying to call the instance.

```
loss_obj = ReconstructionLoss(kwargs_here)
value = loss_obj(args)
```

instead of:

```
loss_obj = ReconstructionLoss()
value = loss_obj(args, kwargs_here)
```